# Read envFrom values secretRef inside configmap

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, configmap, aws-parameter-store

I am reading parameter store values and mounting it into volume mnt/secret  i have created one

```
envFrom:
       -secretRef:
           name:password
```

i need to use this env value inside my config map data which has db connection

i tried to use ${password} but its not working

```
configmap_my:
  name: my_Configmap
  data:
    testapplication.yaml: | -
        database:
           password: ${password}
           driverClass: oracle.jdbc.driver
```

Comment: You can't do this as you've described it; Kubernetes does no substitutions or transformations on the content of ConfigMaps.  You tagged this with [tag:kubernetes-helm], though; do you know the actual password as a Helm value, and could you substitute it at that level?

Comment: ACTUALLY THE PASSWORD IS COMING FROM PARAMETERSTORE